# Make Notepad ++ highlight matching if/fi tags

Tags: bash, notepad++

Notepad++ is generally great about highlighting matching tags.  However, in shell scripts, it doesn't highlight if/fi (or case/esac).  Is there any way to make it do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Je sui Charlie edition, it's a bit older, but under the language tab I see no language profile for bash shell.  You might need to make your own syntax highlighting profile using the

> Language -> Define your language...

menu option.  It's not very hard -- I've made custom profiles for Gcode, Gerber files, and others.

There's a great kickstarter for this task [here](https://udl20.weebly.com/introduction.html).